# How do i get value from a React date picker whenever i change the dates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am using a React library called react-date-picker, I want to get the date whenever I change it.

Here is the default code provided by the library to select the date from a dropdown

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),

  };

  onChange = date => {
    this.setState({ date });

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.date} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

what I have tried to do:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
    new: ""
  };

  onChange = date => {
    this.setState({ date });
    console.log("changed");
    this.setState({ new: this.state.date });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.date} />
        {console.log(this.state.new)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

I am trying to store a value into a new state called "new" whenever someone changes the dates, which will trigger the onChange() and eventually store it into "new", then I am trying to do a console.log(this.state.new) for every time someone changes the dates.

I tried a few different approaches too, but failing to get it right.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you storing the new value as a separate value?

Comment: `new` is a keyword, you shouldn't use it like that. But yeah, what's the goal here? If you want to keep the initial date, you need to remove `this.setState({ date });` and change the other line to `this.setState({ newDate: date });` (otherwise you'll simply have the new date in two state vars instead of one, which is pointless)

Comment: @TedBrownlow It is just not working for the original one, so I tried something different

Comment: What do you mean, "it's not working"? How exactly does it fail? And what do you mean by "get the value"? Also, try replacing `{console.log(this.state.new)}` with `{this.state.new}`

Comment: @ChrisG My goal is to get present date when the browser gets a refresh, and when i am manually changing the dates, I want to grab those  to some variable or something, so that i can later use it for as a query parameter in a weather app

Comment: You can get the selected date at any time, using `this.state.date`. here's a working minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-wildflower-9rt41

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to hold the date in state, and if a user updates the date to also store that in state. What you want to do is something like this:

```
onChange = date => {
  // update date and set new to null since first selection
  if ( !this.state.date && !this.state.new ){
   this.setState({ date, new: null })
  // update 'new' date but keep old date in state
  } else if (this.state.date && !this.state.new) {
   this.setState({ new: date})
  // move old new date to date and set newest selection to new
  } else { 
   this.setState({ date: this.state.new, new: date})
  }
};
```

As a side note, setState is asynchronous so it is not advised to call it twice in a row like you have it. If you want to make sure that the setState has finished updating the state before setting state again then you should use the second argument to setState which is a callback function like:

```
this.setState({ property: valye }, () => this.setState({ another_property: value })
```

Comment: I guess this is what I was looking for

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul For the record, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

> onChange={this.onChange}

you can call the function on every change with an arrow function so that you can pass it a value of the event target, like this

> onChange={e => this.onChange(e.target.value)}

Comment: how can i pass literally dates as e.target.value? It sounds rather weird to me

Comment: That datepicker library doesn't work like that, it passes the new date to the function, not the change event like regular inputs.

Comment: then if the value is provided try onChange={date => this.onChange(date)}

Comment: How does this solve OP's problem? That's just a longer way of what OP already has in their code. I downvoted because I know for a fact that this answer provides bad information and therefore isn't helpful.

Comment: because what he is trying to do is to just get the new value

Comment: I'm guessing OP's main issue stems from the fact that `setState` is async, so their handler function doesn't work as they expect. I still fail to see how your answer even addresses this. And it still has code that will result in a null reference error.

Comment: It works fine, just tried it, but is no need do it like this. Your solution is more elegant since the value is returned from datepickers onChange method.